# .Net C# Dependency Injection resolve ICommands same type

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, autofac, icommand

I have a class with many `ICommands` in the constructor parameters.

```
var classWithManyCommands = 
            new ClassWithManyCommands(new AddItemsCommand(new StringService()),
                                      new AddItemsCommand(new IntegerService()),
                                      ...);


public ClassWithManyCommands(
  ICommand command1,
  ICommand command2,
  ICommand command3,
  ICommand command___,
  ICommand command50,
)
{
  _command1 = command1;
   ...
}
```

When I would register the *ClassWithManyCommands* and the commands in my DependencyInjection container (in my case AutoFac), it would not be able to resolve it automatically.

Would it be a good procedure, to store the `ICommands` in an Object like *AddCommandsContainer*, where they are created? This is not IoC, I know.

```
var addCommandsContainer = new AddCommandsContainer(new StringService(), new IntegerService());
var classWithManyCommands = new ClassWithManyCommands(addCommandsContainer);

public ClassWithManyCommands(AddCommandsContainer addCommandsContainer)
{
  _command1 = addCommandsContainer.command1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Do these commands have a meaning or are those the actual names of the commands? Are they related? Are they always used together? If so perhaps you could "group" related commands in such a container but with a reasonable name, ie "ICarCommands", "ITrainCommands"

Comment: yeah, they are all in one domain, like "car" or train.

Comment: If you need all implementations of `ICommand` in the container, you could inject `IEnumerable<ICommand>`.

Comment: @weichch then I would still have a hard time differentiating "AddItemsCommand(new StringService())" and "new AddItemsCommand(new IntegerService())" since they both will be of the type ICommand and AddItemsCommand

Comment: It might be beneficial to experiment with different design patterns. There might be patterns more suited than the Command Pattern. For instance, did you consider [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/commands/)?

Comment: yep, I saw it but in the application we are working with legacy code and many different implementations of ICommands. Some use a decorator, at some places a CommandHandler is used but it is not always the same style. So there is somehow no one pattern fits all approach.

Comment: So you don't have many `ICommand` implementations, you only have `AddItemsCommand` which accepts different types of services? What does the constructor of `AddItemsCommand` look like?

Comment: I have many many different implementations of `ICommand`. Some ware wrapped, some aren't. The constrictor of `AddItemsCommand` uses the `StringService` for the `Execute` method.